# Ajax requests in laravel. send variables to a controller then to a view

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to implement a AJAX request in my laravel project that load html content when clicking on a specific item of a list.

My view :

```
@for($i=0; $i < count($extras); $i++)
   <li data-cardid="{{$i+1}}" class="showCard">{{ $extras[$i]->type }} Extra: {{ $professional[$i] }}</li>
@endfor
```

then further :

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column; width:60%; align-items:center" id="card-container">
    <!-- THE CONTAINER -->
</div>
```

My script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var url = "{{route('getCard')}}"
</script>

$(".showCard").click(function(){
    var idCard = $(this).data('cardid');
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        data: {id: idCard},
        success: function(card){
            $card = $(card)
            $("#card-container").fadeOut().html($card).fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

My controller :

```
public function getCard(Request $request){
    $cardId = $request->['id'];
    $extra = DB::table('extras')->where('id', $cardId );
    return view('user.card-content', ['extra' => $extra]);
}
```

Here is the card-content view :

```
<img src="{{ asset('../resources/assets/images/extra-background.png') }}" class="background-image" style="width:50%;"/>
           <ul>
              <li class="title">KEY DETAILS</li>
              <li>SALARY: {{ $extra->salary }} CHF/Hr</li>
              <li>BENEFITS: {{ $extra->benefits }}</li>
              <li>LANG: FRENCH</li>
              <li>TIME: {{ $extra->date.' at '.$extra->date_time }}</li>
           </ul>
        <p>
           DESCRIPTION : {{ $extra->requirements }}
        </p>
<a href="{{ route('extra_apply', $extra->id) }}" class="apply-button right">APPLY</a>
```

Unfortunately i have this error :

```
500 (Internal Server Error)
```

What did i do wrong ?

Comment: Try changing `$cardId = $request->['id']` to `$request->input('id')`

Comment: Try inspecting element, go to console and see what the response is of the request. If you do not send a specific response message back from your Controller function, it should send the normal laravel stack trace.

Comment: i added a dd function at the beginning of the controller function and it is not triggered which means that the error is in the ajax function

Comment: Not necessarily. If you add dd(); before anything occurs in your function, then the issue may very well be with how your process the request. I still suggest trying what I put in my previous comment. Should look something like this depending on your browser https://gyazo.com/b262902be234c16174f21b92f71f87e6

Comment: Ok but i didn't understand what you supposed me to do ? in the console :jquery.min.js:3 GET http://127.0.0.1/extrasme/public/ajax/getCardContent?id=1 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Seems you are using Chrome, which is different view than Firefox. Click on `127.0.0.1/extrasme/public/ajax/getCardContent?id=1 ` and it should take you to the network section for that request. There should be a column for the uri where the request gets sent to, click that. Then click on the Preview tab that should be on that page. The preview should have the stack trace.